# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte with reading CSV

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, csv, ascii

Trying to read from a CSV file and write the data into an XML file. I am encountering:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 87: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My question is, what is the best way to ignore this kind of error and continue processing the data set. After reading other similar questions, I did add: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to my file but it didn't help

Comment: Properly decode the input, e.g. read as bytes and then do `input.decode("utf-8")` (if your input is utf-8).

Answer (score 1):

You can try opening csv with codecs:

```
import codecs
codecs.open(file_name, 'r', 'utf8')
```

Given that each line will contain '\n' string you will need to apply **line.rstrip()** when looping trough lines.

Note: Please don't try to convert values to str as you will encounter another error there.

Comment: Thanks @Boris, going to try your suggestion

Comment: Please read the edit, that '\n' gave me headaches more than once :)

Comment: This is how I am reading at the moment: 
with open('myFile.csv', 'rb') as ifile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    for rownum, row in enumerate(reader):

Comment: You can first replace **open** inside your with statement with **codecs.open** as i suggested in answer. Then just use for rownum, row in enumerate(ifile):  row = row.rstrip() on the first line of your iteration and it should replace your csv.reader() method.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while reading readme ad long description in setup.py. If you are using `open`, you can use the encoding parameter:

```
with open("README.md", "r", encoding='utf_8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()
```

Comment: integrated python 2.7 open does not have encoding param.